# custom validation using unobstrusive javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I have a text box in my form

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <label>Job Title</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="JobTitle is required and cannot be blank" id="JobTitle" name="JobTitle" type="text" value="TBD" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="JobTitle" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

I have added a custom validator

```
<script>

        $.validator.addMethod('validjobtitle', function (value, element) {

            // Test 'value' for html here. 'value' is the value of the control being validated.
            if ($('#JobTitle').val() == "TBD") {
                alert("test");
                return false;
            }
            else return true; // Return true or false depending on if it passes or fails validation, respectively.
        }, 'Fix job Title');

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('validjobtitle');
</script>
```

On one of the button clicks I validate the elements like  such

```
var validator = $("form").validate(); // obtain validator
var anyError = false;
$step.find("input,select").each(function () {
    if (!validator.element(this)) { 
        anyError = true;
    }
});
```

For some reason my custom validator is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more reading i found out two things

1. remember to not add custom validator inside a DOM ready handler (i.e. don't use $(document).ready() or $(function() { ... })) - the validation should be set up before the document is ready.
2. after creating the validator and adding it to adapter the most imp step is to link it to the element you want validated. And this is done using

   $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#JobTitle').rules('add', 'validjobtitle');
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use build-in ASP.NET MVC Validation

Create model with validation and use in your view.
You will have client/server side validation.